# Good ways to compare graphs of different sizes?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, graph-theory

Sorry if this is a basic question but I was wondering if anyone could help me find out the class of problems this specific question of mine falls into. I was looking for any standard metrics that can be used to compare graphs of different size and connectivity. Specifically, consider the following example:

```
      G1                             G2
      2                              D
      |                             /  \
4 --- 1 --- 3                 C -- A1 - A2 -- E
      |
      5
```

What I am interested in is to capture the notion of stability inside one graph (intra-stability) and relative to another graph (inter-stability). For instance,

**Intra-Stability:**

In `G1`, in my hypothetical metric, `2,3,4,5` all have the same effect were they to be removed from the graph. In `G2`, `C,E` would have the same effect but `D` would have more effect. However, `A1,A2` would have more effect were they to be removed. What I am looking for here is a notion of stability of a graph. I am guessing I could just use the degree of each node to capture the effect of a specific node but am not sure how to compute it for the whole graph per-se.

**Inter-Stability:**

Can we say something about `G1` and `G2` in a relative sense i.e. something like because `G1` has a stability metric `X` and `G2` has `Y` and because `X < Y`, we conclude `G1` is less stable than `G2`? The definition of stable itself is left open but I am trying to capture how unreliable a graph is or how dependent is it on one node.

Can someone point me in the right direction in order to be able to quantify this or at least what this problem is referred to as?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by stability?  It seems you mean that a graph is more stable if removing some nodes has less "effect" on it.  Can you somehow quantify what you mean by this "effect", or tell us what you want to use this for so we can come up with some quantitative definition together?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you for helping me out. My current understanding goes something like this: The node's degree clearly indicates the effect it has on the entire graph. For instance, one notion could say that `G1` is not as stable as `G2` because 1 seems to be a critical node in `G1` and if it fails, the whole graph crumbles. In `G2`, however, even if `A2` fails, the graph is still functional to some extent. But the actual definition of stability itself is quite open ended as of now. In short, I am trying to capture in one single metric how easily a graph can be taken down.

Comment: It seems to me that it is not yet clear to you either what you need, and what "taking down the network" means.  This review paper might be useful: http://www.barabasilab.com/pubs/CCNR-ALB_Publications/200201-30_RevModernPhys-StatisticalMech/200201-30_RevModernPhys-StatisticalMech.pdf  Take a look at section IX, "Error and attack tolerance".  They removed nodes either randomly or by targeting "important" nodes, and looked at how many need to be removed for the network to fall apart into separate components.  This is related to @Randy's answer, but with a more pragmatic approach.

Comment: Starting with that paper and moving back and forward on the citation graph you can find many works dealing with this problem.  But this statistical approach is only useful for very large graphs, it won't be of much help if you have to deal with graph of ~10 vertices only.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes! I think this looks more like it except that I was planning on understanding some networks first. Basically, arrange these networks in the increasing order of stability. I will read the paper and get back in the mean time. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

in graph theory, a cut or cut-set seems to describe your maximal instability description.

as a metric, you may be talking about 'connectivity'

Comment: +1 Thank you for the suggestion. I will see how to utilize cut-set here and get back.